# how to apply div on hover my table td

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

this is my html table code:

```
<table border='1px'>
<tr>
 <td id='td'>first</td>
 <td>last</td>
<tr>
 <td id='td'>newFirst</td>
 <td>newSecond</td>
</table>
```

and here is my one div this.

```
<div class="Not_Editable id-left" >Not Editable</div>
```

i am just create this div when i hover on my table tr first td then want to show on them this div.
and hover on second td then dont show.

here is css for create div as a title label.

```
<style>
.Not_Editable {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #292929;

  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px; /* vertically center */

  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;

  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.Not_Editable:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;

  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  border: 15px solid;
}
.id-left:after {
  border-right-color: #292929;

  top: 50%;
  right: 95%;
  margin-top: -15px;    
}
</style>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9VPPv/

now how can i do this. help me out with this.

Comment: Do you have some jQuery / Javascript code too? Also, your HTML is not correct. Each `<tr>` needs to be closed with a `</tr>`.

Comment: Can you please write a fiddle?

Comment: Also, you should NEVER use the same ID for multiple elements.   Bad programming practice... causes all kinds of problems.

Comment: I think it might be time to implement some kind of translation device on this site. Either that or have potential users submit to a very rudimentary "Can you speak English?" exam. What is the world coming to when we're dishing out free intelligence to the same people that want to burn our country to the ground?

Comment: @RupamDatta check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9VPPv/

Comment: check my answer and fiddle i have solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/G6Cwe/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="Not_Editable id-left"><div class="triangle"></div>Not Editable</div>
<table border='1px'>
    <tr>
        <td class='td tr'>first</td>
        <td>last</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='td tr'>newFirst</td>
        <td>newSecond</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.Not_Editable {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #292929;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.triangle {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right:15px solid #292929;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
```

**js**

```
$('table tr td:first-child').mousemove(function (e) {
    $('.Not_Editable').css('top', (e.clientY + 10) + 'px').css('left', (e.clientX + 10) + 'px').show();
    $('.triangle').show();
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('.Not_Editable').hide();
    $('.triangle').hide();
});
```

Comment: this is my working demo what i want.http://jsfiddle.net/G6Cwe/3/ in them skyblue lable show at hover time i want to change with black lable . no matter create div or do without them.

Comment: also check this i made and nearest to complete but its not possible add div in every td. http://jsfiddle.net/G4WQT/5/

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that you don't have unique ids for your `td` elements and this is not valid.

My guess is that you're doing a selector by id expecting to get multiple results. Id based selectors returns 0 or 1 elements.

To make this more clear, if you have something like this

```
$('#td').hover(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

event handler will only applies to first td matching the selector.

To make things worse, your table html is incorrect. You should have something like this

```
<table border='1px'>
<tr>
 <td class='td'>first</td>
 <td>last</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class='td'>newFirst</td>
 <td>newSecond</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And then you could change your js logic to

```
$('table .td').hover(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Comment: this is my working demo what i want.http://jsfiddle.net/G6Cwe/3/ in them skyblue lable show at hover time i want to change with black lable . no matter create div or do without them.

Comment: also check this i made and nearest to complete but its not possible add div in every td. http://jsfiddle.net/G4WQT/5/

Answer (score 0):

something along these lines would work:

first, define a  that it should have the specific rollover

```
<table border='1px'>
<tr>
 <td class="td not-editable">first</td>
 <td>last</td>
<tr>
 <td class="td">newFirst</td>
 <td>newSecond</td>
</table>
```

(p.s. you should be using class instead of id if it isn't unique)

secondly, inject the div into the td once a user rollsover the element (and remove it on mouseout)

```
var el = $('<div class="Not_Editable id-left" >Not Editable</div>');

$('td.not-editable').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    var b = e.target.append('el');
    e.target.on('mouseout', function(e) {
        b.remove();
    });
});
```

I haven't debugged this code, but it is definetely the way forward if you want to use a JS implementation

Comment: this is my working demo what i want.http://jsfiddle.net/G6Cwe/3/ in them skyblue lable show at hover time i want to change with black lable . no matter create div or do without them.

Comment: also check this i made and nearest to complete but its not possible add div in every td. http://jsfiddle.net/G4WQT/3/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('#td1').hover(function(){
$('.Not_Editable').show();
},function(){
$('.Not_Editable').hide();
});
```

Fixed the html, changed the id from td to td1 & td2 and closed the `<tr>`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G4WQT/1/)

Comment: yes this type but as hover time div and td display : inline both in one place

Comment: this is my working demo what i want.http://jsfiddle.net/G6Cwe/3/ in them skyblue lable show at hover time i want to change with black lable . no matter create div or do without them.

Comment: also check this i made and nearest to complete but its not possible add div in every td. http://jsfiddle.net/G4WQT/5/

Answer (score 0):

even better; a pure CSS solution

html

```
<table border='1px'>
    <tr>
             <td class="td not-editable">first<div class="Not_Editable id-left" >Not Editable</div></td>
             <td>last</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td class="td">newFirst</td>
             <td>newSecond</td>
         </tr>
    </table>
```

and the css

```
td.not-editable > .Not_Editable {
    display: none;
}

td.not-editable:hover > .Not_Editable {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: this is my working demo what i want.http://jsfiddle.net/G6Cwe/3/ in them skyblue lable show at hover time i want to change with black lable . no matter create div or do without them.

Comment: also check this as your answer i made and nearest to complete but its not possible add div in every td. http://jsfiddle.net/G4WQT/5/